# Is there GetTextExtentPoint Equivalency for Current .NET/Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-cognitive-services

Is there an equivalent of the old GetTextExtentPoint function for working with the global language fonts that are supported by Azure Cognitive services in a Xamarin Label to calculate the required Label height for the provided text content? E.g. given specific text content translated into various languages at runtime because cultural settings, calculate the number of rows needed to display it by determining the number of line breaks needed given potential word wrap.

Comment: Hi Marc, no there's nothing regarding text size in Cognitive Services.

Comment: As a result, I ended up creating my own function to calculated the needed rows based on the average character width.